# How to make ack include .conf files?

Tags: grep, ack

How to configure ack (sometimes distributed as ack-grep) to always include .conf files into search?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the following to your `.ackrc` file:

```
--type-set=conf=.conf
```

Personally, I have one line in my `.ackrc`, which tells it to search all files:

```
-a
```

Comment: If you're using -a, then you might as well be using grep.

Comment: @Andy `-a` still skips certain (almost always unwanted) directories and a few file types. And I still find ack's default output mode to be more pleasing than grep

Comment: Nowadays I always type ack-grep -ai <searchstring> because I have too many servers to configure :)